# Can we set layout of PERT and CPM left to right

Tags: javascript, html, graph, diagram, cytoscape.js

I need to show PERT-CPM flow in which node position should get generated from left to right  and generate the graph with input as vertex(node) and precedence of vertexes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dagre layout.  It will give LTR alignment, but I think it's placement is based on topology rather than a specified position.

You can try the Cola layout, which has more constraints.  However, it's a physics simulation layout so it's more expensive.